# Mask R-CNN mask coordinates

Tags: tensorflow, coordinates, mask, faster-rcnn, matterport

Is it possible to get the results or coordinates of the mask detection or the bounding box surrounding the image? I am using Mask R-CNN from matterport and the visualization of the masks on the image works quite good, but I woukd like to save the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are using this model. But when you import their model and use the `detect` method (which is the straightforward way to use their model), then the coordinates are returned immediately.

See for an explanation of what is returned from `model.detect` this [documentation](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/3deaec5d902d16e1daf56b62d5971d428dc920bc/mrcnn/model.py#L2487).

In short, per image you get a `dict` and your coordinates will be `the_dict["rois"][1]`.

Comment: Thanks. But is it also possible to extract the mask coordinates? I want to extrakt those so that it is possible to pick up the object via a robot gripper.

Comment: Of course for that you'd need to know how the actual coordinates translate into the image. E.g., if (0, 0) in your image corresponds with (x, y) in real space, then you can translate that. It is not possible without this.

Comment: Alright, is there a way to extract the coordinaes with r['masks'] as ist only returns a boolean or do you have to use a different approach?